# Alphabetize characters in a string then put the alphabetized characters into a new String?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, methods

So I have to take a string in an array, put the string into a new array as all characters, sort the characters in alphabetical order, then I need to put the new alphabetized chars into a new string, then print it.

How would I make a method to alphabetize a character array then convert the array to one string?

Comment: Could you post example of input and expected result?

Comment: Could you show us some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm away from my desktop right now, i'll edit with what I have when I get back.

Comment: Do you need to deal with mixed case strings..?

Comment: What about surrogate pairs?

Comment: Just very basic stuff. Haven't learned surrogate pairs and the strings are all lower-case in the text file we're given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
char[] a = ...;
Arrays.sort(a);
String s = new String(a);
```

Comment: You never explained converting a string to char array?

Comment: It was not a part of the question. "How would I make a method to alphabetize a character array then convert the array to one string?"

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {          
    String str = "hello";
    char [] array = str.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(array);
    String sortedStr = new String(array);
    System.out.println(sortedStr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] array = yourString.toCharArry();
Arrays.sort(array);
youNewString = new String(array);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but I probably should have been a little more clear. I know how to convert a string to a character array. I'm just looking for how to sort the character array then convert the alphabetical character array to a new string.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:

```
String s = ... ;
String sSorted = Stream.of(s.split(""))
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deal with mixed case strings, e.g. edcbaABCDEF, then you'll need to do things a little differently...

Arrays.sort() in the other answers only deals with numeric character value, so you'll get edcbaABCDEF => ABCDEFabcde

Arrays.sort(arr, comparator) can only be used with wrapper types, i.e. Character, not char, so you'll need to wrap it first.

```
Character [] wrapped = new Character[charArray.length];
int i = 0;
for (char c : charArray) {
    wrapped[i++] = c;
}
```

Then sort

```
Arrays.sort(wrapped, new Comparator<Character>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
        return Character.compare(Character.toLowerCase(o1),
                Character.toLowerCase(o2));
    }
});
```

Convert back to a string

```
i = 0;
for (char c : wrapped) {
    charArray[i++] = c;
}
System.out.println(new String(charArray));

==> AaBbCcDdEeF
```

This can be simplified using Apache commons lang [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) helper.

```
String test = "edcbaABCDEF";
Character[] charArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(test.toCharArray());
Arrays.sort(charArray, new Comparator<Character>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
        return Character.compare(Character.toLowerCase(o1),
                Character.toLowerCase(o2));
    }
});
System.out.println(new String(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(charArray)));
```